# Can't figure out if two arrays are equal

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm trying to find a way to tell if one of my arrays is longer than the other. I am given a function prototype:

```
 template <typename T, typename U> bool equal(T *left, T *end, U *right);
```

where left is the first array and right is the second array. "end" belongs to the first array and it tells me when the array ends. I am getting some complications when the left array is smaller than the second array. Since I know the ending position of the first array, I was trying to figure out if the second arrays values are passed in values or garbage.

so far I have this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool equal(T *left, T *end, U *right)
{
  int i = 0;

  while(left + i != end)
  {
    if(*(left + i) == *(right + i))
    {
      ++i;
      continue;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It is only working if the arrays are the same size.

Test where it is failing:

```
static void TestEqual2(void)
{
  cout << "***** Equal2 *****" << endl;
  int i1[] = {-1, 2, 6, -1, 9, 5, 7};
  short i2[] = {-1, 2, 6, -1, 9, 5, 7, -1, -1, 8, -1};

  int size1 = sizeof(i1) / sizeof(int);
  int size2 = sizeof(i2) / sizeof(short);

  CS170::display(i1, i1 + size1);
  CS170::display(i2, i2 + size2);
  bool same = CS170::equal(i1, i1 + size1, i2);
  if (same)
    std::cout << "Arrays are equal\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Arrays are not equal\n";
}
```

std::vector is off limits as well as for loops.

Comment: you need to pass either size of 2nd array or *rightEnd to this function to accomplish your tasks

Comment: equal() doesn't have enought information to compare arrays' sizes. You either have to pass this information to the function or compare sizes before you call equal(). You may also take a look at std::array (c++11) although this is not exactly what you described

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the end of the right array also.

template 
    bool equal(T *left, T *end, U *right, U* end2)
    {
      int i = 0;

```
  while(left + i != end && right + i != end2)
  {
    if(*(left + i) == *(right + i))
    {
      ++i;
      continue;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
  return left + i == end && right + i == end2; // return true only if both arrays have the same length
}
```

You also need to change the call to this function into

```
bool same = CS170::equal(i1, i1 + size1, i2, i2 + size2);
```

Comment: If only it was that simple, the driver tests can't be changed for assignments.